# Design guidelines for open in new tab - Hyperlink vs Image

Tags: image, tab

I am designing a website which has lots of 3rd party web services dependency. Hence user need to constantly switch to those site for validation - like using Oauth services, which will redirect back to our site.

What would be the better design for such case -

1. Text HyperLink URL - Which state the description and domain name to
   be redirected.
2. Using the logo of the redirecting site.
3. Any other solution ?

Any similar design example would be helpful.

Comment: Neither text URL nor logo of the target indicate that link will open in new tab - what exactly are you hoping to convey to your users?

Comment: There will be a clear indication text saying users need to authenticate from 3rd party app. Its like OAuth signin where we get redirection after the user complete his action on those sites.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so important whether you use hyperlinks or images as whether you can clearly indicate that you are taking the user to a new tab, and that you will return the user to the previous tab once the operation is finished.

It is about establishing a clear visual indicator and implementing a consistent behaviour, and your users will become used to it.

Here are some examples from a previous question you can reference: [How to indicate this button/link opens a new tab](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55419/how-to-indicate-this-button-link-opens-a-new-tab)